# Correct use of "proof-of-concept"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives, writing-style, technical

In writing a technical paper, I'm wondering about the correct use of *proof-of-concept*.

In short, the situation is that we have developed an application/tool to show the feasibility of a new approach to a problem, i.e. a proof-of-concept.

Now in the paper itself, which of the following would be better to use?

> - Therefore, the proof-of-concept tool proposed in this paper...
> - Therefore, the proof-of-concept proposed in this paper...

I'm not sure how to formally say this in English, but I guess the question is: can *proof-of-concept* be used to refer to the thing itself, or is it used as an adjective?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you are describing a prototype, along the lines of the "beta" phase of software testing.  A prototype need not be a physical object, by the way, but simply an exemplar that performs the way the finished product will perform.  To be honest, I am not familiar with the proof-of-concept locution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Proof-of-concept*" is not an adjective, but rather a noun.

[Proof-of-concept](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proof_of_concept) :

1. A short and/or incomplete realization of a certain method or idea to demonstrate its feasibility.
2. A proof of technology or pilot project.

I would use just "proof-of-concept" instead of using "proof-of-concept tool" as the **tool itself** is your POC! Adding the "*tool*" is a redundancy in my opinion.

Comment: Hmmm I suppose thats true. It baffles me though that the use of proof-of-concept as an adjective seems quite widespread. Especially in literature in my area.

Comment: I disagree with that Wikipedia definition, if it's implying that *proof-of-concept* is normally a noun. So far as I'm aware, it's usually an ***adjective***. Most instances of ["is a proof of concept"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is+a+proof+of+concept%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are followed by another noun which is being adjectivally modified by the preceding term.

Comment: A Google book searchshows both: [noun](http://books.google.com/books?id=bQcfCKQKn18C&pg=PA42&dq=%22proof-of-concept%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CGFDUdzsEMPl4APl4YGYBw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22proof-of-concept%22) & [adj.](http://books.google.com/books?id=HSeE7rOXKsUC&pg=PA157&dq=%22proof-of-concept%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2GBDUeH_OZTe4APYvYCgAw&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22proof-of-concept%22)